# Intermediate Value Theorem and Discontinuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I am asked to find an example of a discontinuous function$ f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}$ where the intermediate value theorem fails. I went over the intermediate value theorem today
Let $f : [a, b] → \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose that there exists a $y$ such that $f(a) < y < f(b) $ or $ f(a) > y > f(b).$ Then there exists a$ \ \ c ∈ [a,b]$ such that $f(c) = y$.
 I understand the theory behind it, however, we did not go over many example of how to use it to solve such problems so I do not really know where to begin

Comment: Have you seen some examples of discontinuous functions? When you think of a function that is not continuous, what is the first example that comes to mind?

Comment: Hint: a discontinuous function need not take every value. If a function has just one value it is constant, hence continuous. What is the next-simplest case? Can you find a function where the intermediate value fails on every non-trivial subinterval of $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Look for a function with a jump discontinuity.

Comment: I keep thinking of f(x)=1/x but I do not know what to do with applying the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Well, $f(x)=1/x$ is not discontinuous at all on its domain, so you need something that *really* jumps.

Comment: As in something like a piecewise function? Like F(x) = 1 for x = 0 and F(x) = 2 for x not equal to 0?

Comment: @user72195 Your example works perfectly.